# php - Dynamic email address variable Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm quite a newbie in php and I got stuck. I would like to create a dynamic email variable which will take email address from a current user and insert it into a link. It will be used to sign up for a mailing list. My mailing list service provided me with instructions to use this code:

```
<?php

$email =
$kod = MD5($email.”SECRET CODE“);
file(“http://www.samplesite.com/get.php?uid=YOUR_UIDemail=$email&kod=$kod&”);
?>
```

I previously used

```
<?php 
 global $current_user;
 get_currentuserinfo(); 
echo    $current_user->user_email ; ?>
```

to obtain current user email for different things but in this instance its impossible. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this url for getting the current user email

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user